# Problems using D'alemberts Ratio test for convergence or divergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series, geometric-series

The geometric series is as follows :

$$n/2^n$$

I am using the ratio test therefore comparing : $$(n+1/2^{n+1})/ (n/2^n)$$

my next line of work is :

$$(n+1/2^{n+1}) * (2^n/n)$$

however I am not familiar with multiplying fractions of this sort, so cannot continue.

my tutor has the next line as .. $$Un+1/Un = (n+1/n) * (1/2)$$

which I do not understand.

Please could someone explain the steps to me in layman's terms so I can deduce an answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For more than one symbol in a subscript or  superscript use "{ }". E.g. 2^{n+1} gives $2^{n+1}$ and  \lim_{n\to \infty} gives $\lim_{n \to \infty}$.

Comment: Thankyou I shall use this in future :)

Comment: You can also just write $(a+b)(c+d)$ without the asterisk. Sometimes for legibility, a multiplication sign is desired.  I recommend \cdot , as A\cdot B gives $A\cdot B$. For fun, try this thing:  \frak {A bcde}.

Comment: Thanks this will definitely be used in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{2^n}n =\frac{n+1}n\cdot\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}n\cdot\frac{2^n}{2^n\cdot 2}=\frac{n+1}n\cdot\frac12.$$

Comment: This makes lots of sense, thank you. through a loophole in the education system I have gone straight from GCSE grade mathematics to further engineering mathematics, not complaining. but there are lots of holes in my understanding , especially in the area of algebraic manipulation. thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for the ratio (which is correct) is $((n+1)/2^{n+1})\cdot(2^n/n)$, which equals $((n+1)/n)\cdot (2^n/2^{n+1})$.  Now, $2^n/2^{n+1}={1\over 2}$, and $(n+1)/n=1+1/n$.  Your expression for the ratio therefore simplifies to $(1+1/n)\cdot {1\over 2}$.  This ratio is $<1$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Indeed, $n\ge2$ works since we get that the ratio is $\le (1+1/2)\cdot {1\over 2}={3\over 4}$.  Thus, the series converges.

As regards your tutor's expression, I don't get it either; as noted above, the correct expression would be $(1+1/n)\cdot {1\over 2}$, and $(n+1/n)\cdot {1\over 2}$ is in error.

Comment: This is great , and has certainly cleared things up for me. Thank you very much for your effort/help